# Chainload EFI grub2 from i386-pc grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader, grub-legacy

Is it possible to chainload grub2 with EFI from i386-pc grub2? I've tried

```
grub> chainloader (hd1,gpt1)/efi/grub/grubx64.efi
```

But I got the "invalid signature" error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the opposite?  Chainloading 32-bit `grub` from a 64-bit `grub`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain-load a 64-bit executable from a 32-bit one, but the opposite is true:  a 32-bit one could be chain-loaded from a 64-bit version, but why would you do that?  Just upgrade the existing to 64-bit and merge the config files instead.

If you're trying to do this because you have 32-bit EFI firmware, you might be out of luck: even though your CPU can support 64-bit (did you check?), you need to upgrade the firmware first from the manufacturer's site, but unfortunately most small brands are not interested in you being able to upgrade your firmware from 32 to 64 bit: *they'd rather have you buy a new PC.*

If you've got a big brand: check the manufacturer's site first.